# Usage of ES6+ syntax in NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am making a npm package which will have a node executable file.

My src folder include an index.js and other helper files in helper folder.

1. I want to use ES6+ syntax.
2. I want to import those helper files in index.js.
3. Build everything and create a single file which will be my executable.

I tried just Babel to build and transpile my code to ES5 but it wont work on imports.
Executable using Webpack + Babel resulted in errors.

Please point me to resource / help which will help me solve this problem

Comment: This [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs) transforms ES2015 modules to CommonJS